# Acumatica Rest API Endpoint query LastModified confirm date is always UTC?

Tags: api, acumatica

I am currently querying a custom endpoint I have created where using a $filter parameter with for example LastModified gt DateTimeOffset'2022-12-12T01%3A33%3A29.583%2B00%3A00' (LastModified gt DateTimeOffset'2022-12-12T01:33:29.583+00:00')

The lastmodified date that value is always in UTC time?

Just want to check so I can convert my local Now date to UTC before hand so the result of the query is correct.  I am just a bit confused by this as on my local instance hosted on my own machine the lastmodified date is saved in local time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acumatica does store datetime in UTC format but review the tips and tricks in the link below to display time in the user's time zone:

https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2019/02/generic-inquiry-tips-tricks.html